# Securing or https for a page isn't working

Tags: java, ssl, https, ssl-certificate, sap-commerce-cloud

The website has properties to secure pages at complete site level and individual page level. If the site level property  is set true, all the pages urls change to "https".
The problem I have is one of the pages isn't secured and this occurs in only production environment. Securing works fine in my local dev and test environment.
What are the other ways to secure a page?

Comment: please post your code, config, the error you get.... basically: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: You application server may be setting SSL incorrectly. Check your domain / IP address  setting in application. Make your question have more information.

Comment: This happens only for a particular page. Rest of them are secured.

Answer (score 0):

You ask a very general question so I'll provide a general answer. Securing pages or subsets of pages can be handled in a several ways.

1. You can do it the simple and far less secure way with .htaccess files assuming you are running a server that has .htaccess support enabled.
2. You can use a framework that is appropriate for your development language:
   java: Spring, Struts 2
   php: Laravel, Yii
   javascript: angular

Each framework has its own learning curve and you should consult the documentation.

3. You can host your site somewhere that has integrated security like Google App Engine and AWS.

If you have a systems team you should defer to them or if you are doing this on your own then I strongly recommend you do not try and roll your own security and instead host someplace that provides security as an integrated feature.